# How to add all the subfolders and files to a matlab path in linux

Tags: matlab

I want to run a matlab code in linux servers, without the GUI. My script has many functions which are placed inside subfolders of the folder where I run the code. I want to run the code inside a tmux session so that I can detach from it.  I have tried the code below

`matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('path\to\file.m');exit;" | tail -n +11`

But it seems it is not getting the functions inside the subfolders.
How can I fix this so that it sees files inside all the subfolders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you just need to add the Matlab command `addpath( genpath( 'path\to\' ) )`

i.e.

```
matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "addpath(genpath('path\to\'));run('path\to\file.m');exit;" | tail -n +11
```

`addpath` is the Matlab command to add a path, `genpath` generates the string of all folder and subfolder paths for a given root path, which `addpath` can interpret.

You could instead jump into that directory first using `cd`, i.e.

```
cd('path\to\');addpath(genpath(cd));...
```

Comment: One could also use the `-sd` flag instead of doing *cd*

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I have no idea what I'm doing with system calls, I was just sticking to cosy MATLAB :)